# How to copy a data row from column A to column B, between each data row

Tags: excel

[Troubles with the update formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x9uL.jpg) [Troubles with formula, asking for a missing matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esp1R.jpg) [Steps, I have tried to retrieve data from column B to column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAAz.jpg)
[Know is telling that I insert insufficient arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLUlq.jpg)Good afternoon,

I have column B, with descriptions in Portuguese, row by row and column D with the translations in English:
I'm trying to insert in column D the corresponding translation in Portuguese under each data row in English.

But I can't find any formula to do that, also I didn't find any question like this in the forum.
The only nearest question about, is to insert a blank row between data rows with this formula =MOD(ROW(D2),2)=0 or with a filter adding series. And retrieving data with vlookup, as in the attached image.

Comment: Edit your question and post some sample data and what you've tried

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? How many rows in your real data-set?

Comment: Thank you Terry for your answer, I'm using Excel 2019, and in the data sheet are 1.095 rows

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your orientations and and disposition to help me.

Comment: I was trying to insert a empty row between each row. in this way:
Inserting a column to the left of Column A.
In the empty column I enter “1” in the row with the 1st row of data.
Them I put an AutoFill the number down.
At the bottom of the screen by the Column A, I clicked on the AutoFill options box them I select Fill Series..

Comment: This allows me to have in the repiated number an empty row. Then I copy a number of the beginning of each description in Portuguese and in the empty row, I create a vlookup formula to retrieve the text in every row. But I know that this is not the right way to do.Should be a complex formula to do in just a step. I already asked many persons about this question, but nobody that I know are able to do. That's why I wrote to stackoverflow, because here have excel experts with abilities to create special and complex formulas. I'm grateful for sharing your experience.

Comment: Kelcher (and @Terry w): Please If you have further problems or clarifications, first ask yourself how you could make this clear for anyone and then amend *the question* so that anyone who sees this the first time can relate. Stackoverflow wants to provide a series of questions and their answers for anyone to find and use. Its *not* a free help forum where others work for you. I dont mean to put you down, just make clear what is expected of the Question in return for the answer(s).

Comment: @Johanness thanks for cc me otherwise I will definitely forget about this question. The OP is new to this community and unfamiliar with the rules but I think he (or she) is getting the idea now, and given that he/she had shown his/her own effort I am happy to help him/her out just like what you did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use power query to tackle this task.

I have used the following data for demonstration. Please note I am using **Excel 365 English version**.

```
| Portuguese | English |
|------------|---------|
| um         | one     |
| dois       | two     |
| três       | three   |
| quatro     | four    |
| cinco      | five    |
| seis       | six     |
| Sete       | seven   |
| oito       | eight   |
| nove       | nine    |
| dez        | ten     |
```

Steps are:

1. Load/Add the data set to Power Query Editor;
2. Make a duplicated column of `Portuguese`, then add an **Index column** with index starting from `1`, then you should have something like below:

[image: Added Duplicate and Index Column]

3. Use **Merge Columns** function under `Transform` tab to merge the `English` column with the `Portuguese - Copy` column with a custom delimiter such as hashtag `#` (as long as this delimiter is not part of your original texts), then you should have:

[image: Merged]

4. Use **Split Columns** function under `Transform` tab to split the merged column by the same delimiter `#`, and make sure in the Advanced Settings to choose to put the results into **Rows** as shown below:

[image: Splited]

The output will look like the following:

[image: Output]

You can choose to remove the `Portuguese` column if you do not want to show it in the final output, then **Close & Load** the table to a new worksheet (by default).

Here are the power query **M Codes** behind the scene. All functions used are within GUI so should be easy to follow and execute.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Portuguese", type text}, {"English", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Portuguese", "Portuguese - Copy"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Added Index",{"English", "Portuguese - Copy"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("#", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you Terry for your help, I will try and after I give a feedback to you

Comment: Good evening Terry, sorry for be late to answer, but until now I cud check your option to solve my request. But thanks a los

Comment: Good evening Terry, sorry for being late to answer, but until now I could check your option to solve my request. But thanks a lot, finally this were the real solution. Now I have my file working properly. For me, was more than little hard, because never before I worked with Power Query. But is a very useful tool, Now thanks to you I started to learn this new option for me. Also, thanks for being so clear and step-by-step explain to me, with appropriate screenshots. Thank you again, you have helped me too much.

Comment: @Kelcher you're welcome... to the world of power query :]

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in the Result Column and adjust $A$1 to your first portuguese term and $B$1 to you first translated term:

```
'=OFFSET($A$1;((ROW()-ROW($B$1))/2)-ROW($A$1)+1;0)
```

You should get a Column, where every Portuguese term is repeated. Now you can overwrite the formulas in the upper cells with the english translations.

The formula calculates the difference between current (translated row) cell and the first translated row and cuts it in half: that is the row of the portuguese term to associate with this cell. Then it uses that row number as offset to the first row of portuguese terms.

Now, if you want to have the forst row empty, you can of course fill the whole formula in the `true` part of an `if` formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$1),2)=0;"";OFFSET($A$1;((ROW()-ROW($B$1))/2)-ROW($A$1)+1;0))
```

That is something you will often do in excel and I assume you know that trick. It  makes the core formula a little harder to read, but it basically says: *if the current row inside this block is divisible by two, then set the row empty, else set the row equal to the formula I presented above*.

Comment: Thank you Johanness, I'm having troubles with the formula. First is asking me the matrix, them I include the column with Portuguese terms. But after is telling that I put insufficient arguments.

Comment: Johanness, I attached 2 screenshot, to show you the error are reporting.

Comment: No wonder. You dont use the formula I have posted. Before asking for help with an answer given, please always make sure, oyu at least copy it correctly.

Comment: Change the LINS)$A$2 to LINS($A$2; If it still toesnt work, feel free to ask. Otherwise check the "accept answer" button so others see that this is solved.

Comment: The formula now are working, but are retrieving only from a single cell reference and do not insert a row under the English sentence. I'm showing you in the screenshot that the formula is the same you gave me, the only difference is the formulas translations and that are requesting for a matrix reference to retrieve the information.

Comment: What do you mean by retrieveing from a single cell reference? You have to copy the formula to all the cells in the area you want it to be....

Comment: The formula I need, should be must retrieve from the first row in column A that are the meaning in Portuguese and insert a row under each corresponding English terms, with the translation in column B. But the formula is retrieving only from a 12 row in column A, as the screenshot I sent.

Comment: Did you autofill the formula to the cells below (little black dot in the bottom-right corner)?

Comment: Thank Johanness for still suporting me, but now I having troubles with the new formula, still retriving only from row 12 and now are a blind row between rows, I sent to you a screenshot, so you can see better the situation.

Comment: Somehow my last comment didnt upload. So I try again: You still ask me to check your typos! It took me 10 minutes to find out that the translation of ROW is LIN and not LINS. Please: if something doesn't work htat people want to help you with: try finding the problem at your end first, before letting others eliminate your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you Johanness for your time and interest to help me, I appreciate that. About the translation of ROW to LIN in Portuguese, The first one that is asking for a matrix, don't allow LIN and suggest LINS them accept Enter otherwise back to show and error, and the same happen with the last before (LINS), also don't allow (LIN) I take care about correct characters in a formula, I know is basic and very important, to work properly.

Comment: 10secs on google : [link](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/lin-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-lin-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)